# How to consider a moment of a force as a 2-form?

Tags: differential-geometry, rotational-dynamics, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, torque

My major is mechanical engineering. Recently, I'm reading "The Geometry of Physics An Introduction (3ed)" by Theodore Frankel.

On page lix in the section O.r, the author discussed the concept of moment physically and mathematically as quoted below.

> The moment about the origin, of a force $ \pmb f$ at position vector $\pmb r$ is, $\pmb r \times \pmb f(\pmb r)$, but this expression makes no sense in more than 3 dimensions. But moments and torques surely make sense in any Euclidean $\Bbb R^n$, indicating that we have not understood mathematically the notion of moment. Now in cartesian coordinates in $\Bbb R^n$, if we replace $\pmb r$ and $\pmb f(\pmb r)$ by 1-forms $\mathit r=x^adx^a$ and $\mathit f=f_c(\pmb r)dx^c$, then $\mathit r \land f$ does make sense as a 2-form at the origin of $\Bbb R^n$ and its components, in the case of 3 dimensions, coincide with those of $\pmb r \times \pmb f(\pmb r)$.

Here are my questions:

1. How to consider the position vector $\pmb r$ as a 1-form?

EDIT: I can understand that a force can be viewed as a 1-form since its action on a virtual translation (a tangent vector belongs to $T_{\pmb r}\Bbb R^3$) gives some virtual work. However, if we consider $\pmb r$ as a 1-form, I can't figure  out on which tangent vector the action of  $\pmb r$ gives a real number.

2. If we consider a moment of a force as a 2-form, then how to calculate the virtual work by means of the action of a 2-form on some pair of tangent vectors?

EDIT: In the case of $\Bbb R^3$, the moment of $\pmb f$ is given by $\pmb M =\pmb r \times \pmb f(\pmb r)$.  Let consider the virtual work done by this moment over a virtual rotation $\delta \pmb \theta$ (a tangent vector in a tangent space of SO(3)). From the notation of $\pmb M$, the virtual work can be viewed as the action of 1-form $\pmb M$ (a covector in a cotangent space of SO(3)) on the tangent vector $\delta \pmb \theta$. When starting from the notation of $\pmb r \times \pmb f(\pmb r)$, if we consider the moment as a 2-form, I want to know on which pair of tangent vectors the action of this 2-form gives the same virtual work.

Comment: 1. Does the very section you quote not *explicit say that*? Can you be more precise about what's unclear to you here? 2. Why do you think you need to compute "virtual work" like that? The author is merely offering a different geometric interpretation of what the moment of force is, none of the formulae involving it change since the components of the 2-form are the same as that of the cross product.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Thank you very much! I have reedited my question. If it's still not clear enough, please let me know. 1.The quotation is taken from the book exactly. 2.  I'd like to know the geometric meaning of each term in the defintion $\pmb M=\pmb r \times \pmb f$ in the case of $\Bbb R^3$, and how to calculate the virtual work starting from each side of the definition. Thanks again!